# Questions about the implementation of async programming on OS level

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, io, operating-system

I am not convinced about some of the claims on the implementation of async programming.

I know that if a thread requests "any" IO operations such as reading a buffer of a file descriptor(stdin, stdout, etc), listening to a pipe, reading and writing on sockets or hard drives immediately send the corresponding thread to the "blocked state". CPU doesn't handle this thread until it turned to the "ready state".

My question is, How does a program exploit a single(main) thread to do IO tasks without creating multiple threads which are assigned to each IO task.

My second question is if async programming is implemented via multiple threads even they are lightweight ones why it is called single-threaded in the cases like NodeJS or Javascript.

My third question is, if async programming is implemented via multi-threads how does it provide memory efficiency?

thanks for the answers.

Comment: If it is implemented at the OS level it doesn't have anything to do with user threads at all.

Comment: While the questions are interesting, they are pretty broad and not very clear/precise. Thus, this is not easy to answer and the provided answers (if any) are likely to be vague. Please ask one detailed question per post.

Comment: @JérômeRichard thanks a lot, but I was supposed to make a decision tree with my questions because I am really curious in that order and it is good to search for answers in that order to understand the whole concept.